# Android hide app icon without reboot of device?

Tags: android

Actually i wants to hide my app from home screens. I go though different tutorials, but all of them require reboot of device. Is there any other way of hiding app without reboot of device??
I used this code for hiding this app. This work after reboot.

```
PackageManager pm = getActivity().getApplicationContext()
                    .getPackageManager();
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(getActivity().getComponentName(),
                    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                    PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Answer (score 0):

I try this code, and hide the icon when you close your apps:

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```